# PHP - Count class attributes in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach, array-filter

I have this function, which iterates through an array of objects in search of matching key => value pairs. I'm curious if there isn't an easier (or more graceful) way:

```
function count_class_attr($objects, $obj_key, $obj_val) {
 $count = 0;
 foreach ($objects as $object ) {
   foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
       if ($key == $obj_key && $value == $obj_val){
           $count ++;
       }
   }
 }
 return $count;
}
```

I think below is closer to what I was looking for. I was looping through an array of objects, not an array of arrays - would the function below be as efficient as possible?

```
function count_class_attr($objects, $obj_key, $obj_val) {
 $count = 0;
 foreach ($objects as $object ) {
    if (property_exists($object, $obj_key)) {
       if($object->$obj_key == $obj_val) { $count ++; }
    }
 }
 return $count;
}
```

Comment: You could use [`array_walk`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

Comment: You might be able to skip the property_exists() if the constructor for your object creates it (meaning that the property will always exist) . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than iterating through the $object array, since this is a hash, a simple check if the key/value exists/matches should work, i.e.:

```
if (array_key_exists($obj_key, $object)) {
    if ($object[$obj_key] == $obj_val) {
       $count++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (in_array($obj_key, array_keys($objects, $obj_val))
   $count++;
```

Comment: `in_array()` is a linear search, so there's likely no performance gain here.

Comment: You've got the keys and values backward . . .